# Add a EditText with button

Tags: android, android-layout

I want when I click add icon (+) as this image, it will add more a EditText to add another address. Number address can expand as user want. How I can do that ?
[Add a EditText](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHJHT.png)

Comment: search in google "create edittext programatically in android". you will get idea after this search.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Post something you tried, nothing is impossible

Comment: Thank everyone, I will try :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to take container in which you can addviews at runtime :

For example:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Address"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addAddress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Now you need to add edit text at runtime.

```
final LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addAddress);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    EditText editText = new EditText(HomeActivity.this);
    container.addView(editText);
  }
});
```

Please read more on how to add views at runtime.